# Adding a child in a GestureOverlayView on the point where i touched in android?

Tags: android, view, gesture

How can i add a child(a layout) in a gestureoverlayview at the point where i touched in that view..... Is it possible to position it according to the co ordinates of the location??

Comment: Have you tried using my solution or have you found your own?

Answer (score 1):

**For API 11 (Android 3.0.x) and above:** you can use `View.setX()` and `View.setY()`. See [API docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setX%28float%29) for details.

**For all API versions:** you could use `RelativeLayout` and `RelativeLayout.Layout`. Specifically by setting [margins](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams.html) in fields inherited from `ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams`. I guess it would go something like this:

```
RelativeLayout parentLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relative_layout);

LinearLayout newLayout = new LinearLayout(this); // or some other layout

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
    // You can enter layout absolute dimensions here instead of 'wrap_content'.
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
// Set your X and Y position here for new layout.
layoutParams.setMargins(100 /*left*/, 200 /*top*/, 0 /*right*/, 0 /*bottom*/); 
parentLayout.addView(newLayout , layoutParams);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    TextView tv=new TextView(this);

    switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        x = event.getX();
        y = event.getY();
        RelativeLayout gh = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relative1);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams para = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(150, 50); //Size of textView
        para.leftMargin = (int) x;  //location of textview
        para.topMargin = (int) y;
        tv.setLayoutParams(para);

        tv.setText("You have Touched at  "+x+" ,"+y);
        change();
        gh.addView(tv);
    }
```